# How to clean a string from non valid characters in ruby?

Tags: ruby, encoding, escaping

I am parsing a file and I get this string:

```
"���email@locale"
```

How can I make sure to clean a string that has these invalid chars "�"?

Comment: "�" is the [replacement character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character). It's used to indicate invalid data, often due to wrong encoding. Check the file's encoding and make sure you're reading it correctly. Inspecting the string's [`codepoints`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-codepoints) or [`bytes`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/String.html#method-i-bytes) might also help. It's hard to tell what's wrong without the file or any code.

Comment: You shouldn't clean the string. You should figure out why the string is broken and fix it.

Comment: To expand on my earlier comment: it is highly likely that those characters didn't start out invalid. Instead, they are probably valid in some encoding at the source and got destroyed somewhere along the way by interpreting them with the wrong encoding. In other words: you have a data integrity issue in your system, you are losing or corrupting data somewhere. Cleaning the string does not fix the issue, it simply hides the fact that there *is* an issue. Data corruption / data loss is not something to be taken likely.

Comment: � is a valid character. It purposely indicates the location of data loss due to a bug. Fix the bug instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to remove unwanted characters.

```
"���email@locale".chars.select(&:ascii_only?).join
=> "email@locale"
"���email@locale".gsub(/[^\p{Ascii}]/, '')
=> "email@locale"
```

This will break with domain names that include international characters, which is ok these days.

To allow ascii before the `@` and anything after that, you can use something like this:

```
sanitized_email = "���email@locale"[/\p{Ascii}+?@[^\s]+/]
# now you can check if the email was valid at all:
raise "invalid email" if sanitized_email.nil?
```